# How to darken a fragment that lies in the background?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

I have two fragments, one has the size of the complete view. The other fragment is smaller and is placed over it. How can I darken the first fragment?

Comment: is that other fragment a dialog fragment?

Comment: it is a other fragment

Comment: so you're putting that fragment in your fragment veiw , it is not a dialog, why would you do that.

Comment: I dont know is this not the right way ? I am Beginner in Android Develompment

Answer (score 2):

in fragment XML file you can set background by add this     `android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"`
 in parent element , of course you can change the color .